# An uncaught Exception was encountered (when insert the data into table) in CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

we will INSERT different values in the database
In the application/controller, the file baby_form.php is created.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH')OR exit('No diect script access allowed');

class Baby_form extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->view("baby_form_add");
    }
    function savingdata(){
        //this array is used to get fetch data from the view page.
        $data = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'meaning' => $this->input->post('meaning'),
            'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
            'religion' => $this->input->post('religion')
        );
        //insert data into databse table.
        $this->db->insert('baby',$data);

        redirect("baby_form/index");
    }
}
?>
```

View file (baby_form_add.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Baby Form Add</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('baby_form/savingdata'); ?>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Meaning:</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="meaning"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gender:</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="gender"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Religion</td>
                <td>:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="religion"></td>
            </tr><br><br>
            <tr>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function site_url()

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter3\application\views\baby_form_add.php

Line Number: 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your actual error is site_url() is undefined.
Use the **URL helper** function in your controller.

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

For More information, you can check the following URL related to "URL helpers".

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: this code after implement program is working